# Правописание приставок, заканчивающихся на З и С

Tags: орфография, приставка

В каких случаях приставки заканчиваются на С, а в каких - на З в спорных случаях, вроде "рас/раз", "черес/через" и т.д.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случае, если корень слова начинается на глухую согласную, приставка будет заканчиваться на С.
Примеры: *ра**сп**исание, чере**сч**ур, бесшабашный, на**сп**адать*.
Если же корен начинается на звонкую согласную, приставка заканчивается на З.
Примеры: *и**зр**аненный, во**зв**ращать, ни**зв**одить*

Answer (score 0):

*В русском языке существует ряд приставок, заканчивающихся на **З-/С-** 
(**раз-/рас-, без-/бес-, из-/ис-, вз-/вс-, воз-/вос- и т.д.**).
Выбор написания букв **З** или **С** на конце этих приставок зависит от буквы, с которой начинается корень после приставки. 
Если корень начинается с глухой согласной буквы, то приставка заканчивается на **С**.
Если корень начинается с гласной или со звонкой согласной, то приставка будет заканчиваться на **З**.

- Вы должны помнить, что приставка **С-**
     не подчиняется этому правилу, так как
     приставки **З-** не существует (есть
     слова, корень которых начинается на
     **З-**: **з**десь, **з**дание, **з**доровье, **з**дравствуйте, **з**ги)

Comment: Ещё нужно отметить приставку диз-/дис-, правописание которой регулируется другим правилом.